# Python distrbute questions based on levels

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have n number of questions, which is categorized in three levels (Low, Medium, High)
Based on the number of questions per quiz, I want to show those questions randomly to the end user.

A) If quiz has 7 questions and we have three levels then 3 questions from low, 2 questions from medium and 2 questions from high.
B) If quiz has 8 questions and we have three levels then 3 questions from low, 3 questions from medium and 2 questions from high.

```
quiz_questions = 7
low_question_ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]                                                                                                                                                                
mid_question_ids = [44,55,66,77,88,99]                                                                                                                                                            
high_question_ids = [21, 22, 23, 24,25]    

mod_q = quiz_questions//3
low_question_ids[mod_q] 
mid_question_ids[mod_q] 
high_question_ids[mod_q]
```

I am unable to get the o/p

Answer (score 1):

You need to first find the number of questions to be picked up from each category and then pick that number of ids from the question lists at random.

```
import random

quiz_questions = 7
low_question_ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
mid_question_ids = [44,55,66,77,88,99]
high_question_ids = [21, 22, 23, 24,25]

#find no of question to be picked from each category
no_of_low_questions = (quiz_questions//3)+1

quiz_questions-=no_of_low_questions
no_of_mid_questions = quiz_questions//2 if quiz_questions % 2 == 0 else quiz_questions//2 + 1
no_of_high_questions = quiz_questions - no_of_mid_questions

#use random library to help pick random question ids from each list
print(random.sample(low_question_ids, no_of_low_questions))
print(random.sample(mid_question_ids, no_of_mid_questions))
print(random.sample(high_question_ids, no_of_high_questions))
```